# Use string variable as object fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties

I need to choose a property to animate and then, do animation.

The code should be like a following:

```
var prop = "background-color";
switch( val )
{
   case 1: prop = "color";
   case 2: prop = "border-color";
   // ...
}
item.animate( {prop: "#00FF00"}, 1000 );
```

JavaScript complains about using "prop" variable.

When i just say

```
item.animate( {"color": "#00FF00"}, 1000 );
```

everything is fine.

I think, a constant is expected as object property declaration.

How can i determine it at runtime ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are equivalent:

```
// prop is a literal string here,
// not a variable
{prop: "#00FF00"}
```

and

```
{"prop": "#00FF00"}
```

you probably need to do something like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[prop]="#0000ff";
item.animate( obj, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct, JavaScript expects an identifier as the property name in an object literal. You'll have to create an object and assign the property using square bracket notation.

```
var opts = {};
opts[prop] = "#00FF00";
item.animate(opts, 1000);
```